# Joomla "Modified Date" Format

Tags: joomla

I would like to change the format of the date, which is printed by Joomla when I use `$item->modified;`. Right now it prints something like `2016-01-15 13:11:34`.

I tried to use the language overrides. They work fine for any text but if I change the date, it does not affect the "modified date".

How are the "options" or "variables" like `$item->modified;` called? And even more important to me - how can I change the format of this date?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try with this code:

```
echo JHtml::_('date', $item->modified, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC4'));
```

You can find the different formats for date in this path:
 
**languages/en-GB/en-GB.ini** around line 260

Regards.